# How to measure the SNMP performance of C when compared to other languages?

Tags: c++, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

Iam looking at software that opens up a data set and grabs a list of server ips and pings them. Someone familar with this software packge says there is nothing else faster because the software is built on C++. Short of rebuilding the app in java is these anyway i can confirm what is the best language when building an app around snmp?

I know the question of C performance is posted all over the place but I do not see anything related to SNMP. When your core application is somthing like snmp is there a prefered programing lang?

Comment: Whatever makes *you* (the programmer) more productive. Unless this is code to be run on thousands of network analyzers hundreds of times a day, your time is more valuable than the computer time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of an SNMP client isn't likely to have much to do with the implementation language. The network and the responsiveness of the server are the rate-determining steps.

Comment: I agree and I know the performance of the network plays a major role. This is more in regards to sending out numerous simultaneous pings getting the results and storing them in a dB. I am sure threads play a major role also but this is all relatively new to me.

Comment: Threads are scheduled by the operating system. DBMS performance is determined by the DBMS and is another rate-limiting step. I personally would use Java and the the SNMP4J library for this.

Comment: I agree, and I want to add that the requirement in the question looks almost too simple to be affected by a bad implementation. Sending an SNMP request and checking the answer is trivial, performance-wise. On the other hand, implementing an SNMP Agent (the other side of the communication) has ample opportunity for bad choices of algorithms and data structures. That problem does is not affected much by language choice.